# Intersection of norms on algebras

Tags: normed-spaces, banach-algebras

Let $A$ be an algebra over $\mathbb{R}$. Say a norm on $A$ is a map
$$ | \cdot | : A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$$
such that $|ab| = |a| \cdot |b|$, $|a + b | \leq |a| + |b|$, and $|1| = 1$.

Say a ball is a subset of $A$ of the form $\{ a \in A : |a| \leq 1 \}$ for some norm $| \cdot |$.

Can we characterize subsets of $A$ which are intersections of balls?

$1$ and $0$ are in any such intersecction, and any intersection is closed under convex combinations. Does this characterize intersections of balls in $A$?

Comment: No.  Intersection of balls are closed, so any convex non empty  open  set different from $A$ cannot be an intersection of balls since $A$ is connected (it is a vector space, so it path connected).

Comment: @GreginGre Hopefully there is still a characterization of some sort, such as closed balls.

Comment: Borrowing from the language of locally convex topology, such intersections $S$ will also be balanced (for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ with $|x| \leq 1$, you'll have $x \cdot S \subset S$), and all *finite* intersections of balls will be absorbing (for all $a \in A$, there is some $c > 0$ such that $a \in x \cdot S$ for all $x \geq c$). Hence if you define what "closedness" means, finite intersections will necessarily be barrels, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrelled_space). I'm not sure if you'll be able to draw any reverse conclusions in great generality, though...